# Primitive log-divergent graphs and convergence of Feynman amplitudes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, quantum-field-theory, feynman-integral

To a connected graph $G$, quantum field theory attaches the integral
$$
I_G=\int_{\sigma} \frac{\Omega_G}{\Psi_G^2}
$$ where $N_G$ is the number of edges of the graph, $\sigma$ is the simplex of points $(x_1: \ldots : x_{N_G}) \in \mathbb{P}^{N_G-1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i$, $\Omega_G$ is the volume form
$$
\Omega_G=\sum (-1)^i x_i dx_1 \wedge \cdots \widehat{dx_i} \cdots \wedge x_{N_G}
$$ and $\Psi_G$ is the first Symanzik polynomial, defined by
$$
\Psi_G=\sum_{T \subseteq G} \prod_{e \notin T} x_e, 
$$ where the sum runs over spanning trees.

The integral is in general divergent, but converges for a class of graphs called *primitive log-divergent*. These are those for which $N_G=2b_1(G)$ (first Betti number) and $N_\gamma>2b_1(\gamma)$ for any proper subgraph $\gamma$. I have found this statement in several places but no proof.

Does anybody know how to prove the convergence of $I_G$ in the primitive log-divergent case?

Is it an if and only if?

Any intuition about what the condition means?

Answer (score 4):

A convergence proof ("if and only if") follows proposition 5.2 of [On Motives Associated to Graph Polynomials](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510011) (2005).